# Compare Javascript Object Values

Tags: javascript

I am building an integration and I have two objects. The makeup of the objects is as follows:

```
var objectA = {};
objectA['alpha'] = 'charlie';

var objectB = {};
objectB['bravo'] = 'charlie;
```

What I want to know is given the two objects above is it possible to compare the two value to see if they are different?

Please note that the objects make up are completely different for both objects but I just need to compare the values.

Comment: What exactly do you mean compare? Do you mean something like magicFunction(object,property,object2,property2)?

Comment: `if(objectA.alpha === objectB.bravo)` or `if(objectA['alpha'] === objectB['bravo'])`

Comment: Are you trying to find a way, given two objects, to see if any of their properties match? Will these objects always have one property?

Comment: `objectA.alpha === objectB.bravo)`

Comment: I am looking for a way to see if their properties match. There will not be any nested properties only one property.

Comment: I don't want to compare the entire object. Just the values in the object.

Comment: @Bergi Unfortunately, that still isn't a great dup, since it's about comparing objects, whereas this gentleman is comparing, or rather trying to compare, primitives. The problem is that this question is so elementary and rudimentary that it probably has not been asked before. However, in the interest of keeping the question closed, I guess we should just leave it as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

`objectA.alpha === objectB.bravo`

OR

`objectA['alpha'] === objectB['bravo']`

Assuming `alpha` and `bravo` are not Objects again.

Comment: This will return true if they are equal and false if they are not equal correct?

Comment: Yes of course. You can try that in your browser console.
`var objectA = { alpha: 'charlie' }; var objectB = { bravo: 'charlie' }; console.log(objectA.alpha === objectB.bravo);`

Comment: What's next? Answering a question about how to multiply two values in JavaScript by using the star?